# .NET CORE: inconsistent behaviour for json body deserialization in different controllers

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net, json-deserialization

Building an API in [.NET CORE 3.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core), I need to validate and deserialize json body to a custom class.
What I did for one of my controllers, which is working:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyNS
{
    [JsonObject]
    public class SearchAAA
    {
        [JsonProperty("query", Required=Required.Always)]
        public Query Query { get; set; }
    }

    public class Query
    {
        [JsonProperty("and", Required=Required.Always)]
        public List<And> And { get; set; }
    }

    public class And
    {
        [JsonProperty("property", Required = Required.Always)]
        public string Property { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("operator", Required = Required.Always)]
        public string Operator { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value", Required = Required.Always)]
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The accepted json should have the following structure:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "and": [      
      {
          "operator": "eq",
          "property": "prop1",
          "value": "value1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`Controller1.cs`

```cs
[Route("/v1/aaa/search")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Search(SearchAAA data)
{
    foreach (var q in data.Query.And)
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

To handle invalid json, I've added the following in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // [...]

    services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
            //options.AllowInputFormatterExceptionMessages = false;
        })
        .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => {
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
            {
                string errorMessage = "Validation error";

                foreach (var key in context.ModelState.Keys)
                {
                    if (context.ModelState[key].Errors.Count > 0)
                    {
                        errorMessage = string.Format("Json property '{0}': {1}", key, context.ModelState[key].Errors[0].ErrorMessage);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                int statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

                var dto = new
                {
                    success = false,
                    error = errorMessage
                };

                return new JsonResult(dto) { StatusCode = statusCode };
            };
        });

    services.AddAuthorization();

    // [...]
}
```

This seems to work, if I send invalid json I receive an error response like in the following example:

```json
POST /v1/aaa/search
{
  "query": {
    "joker": [      
      {
          "operator": "eq",
          "property": "prop1",
          "value": "value1"
      }
    ]
  }
}

RESPONSE [400]
{
    "success": false,
    "error": "Json property 'query.and': Required property 'and' not found in JSON. Path 'query', line 10, position 3."
}
```

I am trying to do the same thing in a new controller (need to deserialize different json to a different class object). For whatever reason I could not explain, validation is not triggered. Using debugger I can just see that invalid json will result in a null `data` field, but `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` is not called. Also I've noticed that in the new controller (although basically identical to the first) I need to add a `[FromBody]` attribute to deserialize correctly (while in the first controller this wasn't necessary).

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyNS
{
    [JsonObject]
    public class SearchBBB
    {
        [JsonProperty("fields", Required=Required.Always)]
        public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
    }

    public class Field
    {
        [JsonProperty("property", Required = Required.Always)]
        public string Property { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value", Required = Required.Always)]
        public object Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Controller2.cs`

```cs
[Route("/v1/bbb/search")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Search([FromBody] SearchBBB data)
{
    foreach (var field in data.Fields)
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Even if I try to reuse the class `SearchAAA` in the second controller I get no validation error:

`Controller2.cs`

```cs
[Route("/v1/bbb/search")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Search(SearchAAA data)
{
    // ...
}
```

It seems to me that it should work in the same way for different controllers of the same application, but it doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: How does you controller classes attributes look like? esp are both decorated with ApiController attribute https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.apicontrollerattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0 ?

Comment: Btw. you should be able to simplify your dtos: a) lower case property names in json should work with the default convertion w/o annotations. b) If nullable ref types are enabled, you can often remove the required attribute (if type is not nullable, it's required) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references. Also your error handling looks like the default error handler.

Comment: I am using [ApiController] attribute

Comment: do you have a base class for the controllers in any of the two scenarios?

Comment: Are you sure that, in your second controller, you are really using [tag:json.net] and not [tag:system.text.json]?